# Как произносить слово "мужчина"?

Tags: фонетика

Как произносится слово "мужчина" — *мужщина* или *мущщина*? И почему в орфоэпическом словаре к слову "мужчина" транскрипция **[ущи]**, а не **[ужщи]** или **[ущщи]**?

Comment: Вам же словарь сказал, как произносить. Какие сомнения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В кириллической фонетической транскрипции не принято использовать два одинаковых символа подряд, т. е. [щщ] невозможно. Не [жщ] потому, что произнести это самое сочетание вы сможете, только если изрядно постараетесь; не говорят так. [щи] выбрано, видимо, из-за того, что это просто и понятно, а вообще стоило бы указать на долготу звука: [ущ:и].

Comment: *Не [жщ] потому, что произнести это самое сочетание вы сможете, только если изрядно постараетесь* - нет ничего проще длячеловека, говорящего по-польски или по-чешски. Этот звук почти в точности передаёт "мягкое R"  в этих язіыках.

Comment: @behemothus может быть; мы говорим о русском языке :)

Comment: А я о том, что больших артикуляционных трудностей в этом сочетании нет. )))

Comment: @behemothus для меня нет трудностей в произношении th, но это не значит, что для русскоговорящего все просто. Вы еще вспомните кликсы — их тоже легко произносить. Если ты африканец. Да и то не всякий. А говорить о том, что сочетание звонкий парный + глухой шумный возможно в живой русской речи внутри слова в обычных условиях — это, кхм, необычно.

Answer (score 3):

> Как произносится слово "мужчина" — мужщина или мущщина? И почему в
>   орфоэпическом словаре к слову "мужчина" транскрипция [ущи], а не
>   [ужщи] или [ущщи]?

Если быть максимально дотошным, то произношение можно передать как [мушш'ина] - то есть первый звук **Ш** в этой паре твердый, а второй - мягкий (как **Щ**, но короткий). Такое сочетание звуков в одном слове уникально и в целом совершенно нехарактерно для русского языка, его невозможно воспроизвести даже на стыке слов. 
При этом то, что получается, в общем-то очень близко к привычному нам звуку Щ - и в речи многих носителей полностью ему уподобляется. 
Поэтому использование фонетического знака [Щ] для обозначения рассматриваемого сочетания вполне оправдано.
**Можете произносить именно [мущина] - ошибки не будет.**

(+)---

Вообще история звука Щ в русском и некоторых славянских - это предмет особого исследования. Если копнуть поглубже, то станет понятно, что передача этого сочетания "жч" (и некоторых других) этим звуком не случайна. Звук Щ образовался из древнеславянского сочетания [ш'тш'] в котором Т отвечал за внутризвуковую смычку и постепенно редуцировался. Звонкий вариант этого звука (частично сохранившийся в слове дождь в его устаревающем произношении [дож'ж']) отвердел и перешел в чистое Ж или ЖЖ. А глухой предстал привычным нам Щ. Сочетание же ЖЧ в слове *мужчина* по сути и есть тот исчезнувший древнеславянский звук [ш'тш'] - с почти незаметными на слух отличиями. Это еще раз показывает оправданность использования [Щ] для транскрибирования рассматриваемого сочетания.

Answer (score 1):

Произношение ***му(щи)на*** можно объяснить и в современном языке. Сочетания **СЧ, ЗЧ,  ЖЧ, ШЧ**  произносятся как Щ: *песчаный,  резчик, перебежчик, веснушчатый*.

Как это объяснить?

По способу образования звуки З/С (свистящие) и  Ж/Ш (шипящие) относятся к фрикативным (щелевым) звукам: при их произношение воздух проходит через узкую щель, а звук Ч является аффрикатой, то есть язык сначала смыкается с небом и образуется смычной звук, а потом он переходит в щелевой (фрикативный) звук.

Когда  звуки З/С и   Ж/Ш  встречаются со звуком Ч, то мы фактически должны произносить три звука: **щелевой + (смычной + щелевой),** да еще обозначать звонкость/глухость и мягкость/твердость, а это неудобно.

Поэтому мы упрощаем звуковое сочетание и произносим **один зву**к, а именно **глухой щелевой Ш,** вернее, его **мягкий удлиненный вариант**, а это и есть звук Щ.